# Assign case statement result to variable

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

When I try to run the following statement, I get this error:

"A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations."

```
DECLARE @OFR DECIMAL(18,2)
;
SELECT @OFR = 
CASE SUM(ofr.Quantity)
WHEN 0 THEN 0 
ELSE SUM(ofr.Gross) / SUM(ofr.Quantity)
END
FROM DistributionCosts ofr
;
SELECT @OFR
```

I just want to stick the result of that case statement into a variable and I'm getting stuck here.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: That works for me. Sure you haven't got another column in your query?

Comment: Yeah, I had other columns I omitted, I spaced on it.  Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure this is where your error is?  I just ran the statement below and it worked:

```
DECLARE @OFR DECIMAL(18,2)
;
with DistributionCosts  as
(
  select 1 as quantity, 5 as gross
  union
  select 5 , 20
)
SELECT @OFR = 
CASE SUM(ofr.Quantity)
WHEN 0 THEN 0 
ELSE SUM(ofr.Gross) / SUM(ofr.Quantity)
END
FROM DistributionCosts ofr

;
SELECT @OFR
```

If I select a column in addition to setting a variable I do get your error...  If you are selecting another column you will need to either stop selecting that column or assign that column to a local variable as well.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, I spaced on the other columns...thanks!